# NDB DEBUGGER Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8000

Tags: node.js

I'm using ndb debugger to debug my node-express application. I get the following error when I click on run the script in the chromium browser.

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8000[image: chromium browser error]

Comment: `netstat -nlp | grep :8000` and  `kill pid`

Comment: @ManjeetThakur it did not make any  difference. I keep getting the same error. I'm using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Than change the port

Comment: I get the same error after changing the port

Answer (score 0):

So, I just ran into this issue. Likely, you still have the node process running. Stop the node process and then you will be all set

Answer (score 0):

In order to stop all node processes, you need to stop those, by running the following command in CMD

```
taskkill /F /IM node.exe
```

Comment: taskkill /F /IM node.exe